# How to use a model method within a scope?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a method:

```
def can_book_appointment?
```

and i want to use it in a scope for the activeadmin gem

```
scope :cannot_book_appointment, lambda { |self| , {:condition => !self.can_book_appointment?}
```

I did try

```
scope :place_cannot_book, lambda { PlaceDetail.all.reject{|n| !n.can_book_appointment?} }
```

but i get a error in activeadmin:

> undefined method 'reorder' for #< Array:0x121bf5e8>

I know this doesn't work, but it helps to get an idea of my intention.
How can I use this method on each records of the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. Scopes are applied at the database-level, your `can_book_appointment?` method exists at the model level. They can't interact the way you're trying to make them interact.

You need to define  a second scope that applies the same check that `can_book_appointment?` performs, but at the database level.